# How to disable the Ctrl + Click opening object view function in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

It always gets stuck with no response for long time when I occasionally Ctrl+Click one table name when writing the SQL in the SQL Editor windows of PL/SQL Developer.

Is there anyway to disable this Ctrl + Click opening object view function in PL/SQL Developer?

Do anyone know about it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no.  [Here](https://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=57444&Searchpage=1&Main=15095&Words=click%20view&Search=true#Post57444) is a forum post from 2018 where I asked about this and there has been no change since then.  Also, if you are an avid PL/SQL Developer user the forum is a great place to start with these kinds of questions.